# Removing path from urls in Nginx

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, webserver

My site works correctly as

https://example.com/website/page/Home

https://example.com/website/page/AboutUs

I would like to remove the /website/page part so that end users would see https://example.com/Home etc.
I read on Nginx website that rewrites are not preferred so I tried:

```
Location / {
    try_files $uri /website/page$uri;
}
```

I get an internal serval error. What is the right way?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a rewrite like:

```
# rewrite example.com/awesome to example.com/website/page/awesome
rewrite ^(/.*) /website/page$1 break;
```

This should work similarly:

```
rewrite ^/(.*) /website/page/$1 break;
```